# Syncing Tool Between 2 Folders

Tags: windows, windows-xp, sync

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Which is the best application to Sync two folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders)
>   [Keeping folders synced between several machines](https://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines)

What is a good tool to automatically sync two folders when changes are made to either one of them. I want to sync a folder in the Mozilla Tree (My Greasemonkey Scripts) with a folder on my desktop.

Any suggestions?

Comment: No, I'm asking for automatic.

Comment: OK, I missed that bit.

Comment: Lol how many ways are there to synchronize a folder and post a question about it on SU? ;-)

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/349/keeping-folders-synced-between-several-machines

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am assuming that your sync'ing is within the same machine.
If its across machine, please say so.

[**File Synchronization and Data Backup with Microsoft SyncToys**](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/29694.aspx)

> [**SyncToy**](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en) ([ST](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/windows-platform/articles/29143.aspx)) is free file synchronization software designed by Microsoft to aid the user to synchronize, copy, backup and maintain folders of files on computers. Unlike most other methods, ST acts very fast in synchronizing the files in folders by copying, renaming and deleting files. ST is much simpler to configure and user-friendly.

Also read the [**Automating Sync Toy** section in this article](http://maximumpcguides.com/windows-vista/windows-xp-powertoy-synctoy/).

Comment: Is there a way to make this automatic/scheduled?

Comment: Windows has a task scheduler, see http://superuser.com/questions/6490/windows-equivalent-to-cron and http://superuser.com/questions/8443/schedule-a-job-with-windows-command-line

Comment: Comments describing the negative vote will be appreciated.

Comment: @Chacha102, I added a reference for Automating SyncToy

Comment: I didn't downvote it though.

Comment: Tried it, but ran into problems: http://superuser.com/questions/13493/which-is-the-best-application-to-sync-two-folders/36066#36066

Answer (score 3):

If you want the contents of the two folders to be exactly the same, why not just create an NTFS junction point on the folder? This will effectively make the *same* folder available in both places. Any change you make from one location will instantly happen in the other location, because both locations are actually the same folder.

The [NTFS Link](http://elsdoerfer.name/=ntfslink) shell extensions will let you easily create and manage these junction points (and hard links also) from the Explorer context menu.

Answer (score 3):

For a simple commercial utility, you can try SecondCopy by Centered Systems, or for a more powerful (but more difficult) utility, you can try the free version of [SyncBack](http://www.2brightsparks.com/).

Sorry -- haven't been a user long enough to post the direct links to both...

Answer (score 2):

I use Allway Sync. Works for me. http://www.allwaysync.com/

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to write a script that copies the file based on the archive bit.  he archive bit indicates every file that has been changed. The archive bit exists for the precise purpose of knowing when a file is in need of a backup.

The manual command to do this is below...

```
xcopy c:\fileroot\myfile.txt c:\filecopy\ /A
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx).  A free utility from someone at Microsoft.  Apart from doing what you ask, it is also optimized for the copy process and is faster than most tools I've used to copy multiple files.

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Dropbox](http://www.getdropbox.com/)

```
* Sync files of any size or type
* Share large files and photos easily
* Automatic online backup
* Access your files anywhere
* Sync between operating systems
* Track and undo changes to files
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Dropbox is SpiderOak, which lets you sync arbitrary folders, I think they write their UI in Java though, so it's a bit slugish.

Comment: If you're on OSX or Linux (I know the OP isn't, but someone else may find this helpful), you can run the tool via the command-line with a `--headless` option to cut down on GUI slowness.

Answer (score 0):

**[mesh.com](http://mesh.com)** is a great solution. **Microsoft Live Mesh** syncs folders among macs, pcs and the online desktop. I've been using it for months to sync userjs scripts, college documents and anything, really.