# How can I Synch two folders?

Tags: hard-drive, sync, external-hard-drive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Syncing Tool Between 2 Folders](https://superuser.com/questions/17129/syncing-tool-between-2-folders)

Hi,

I have 1 Extra Hard-drive and want copy some of my file and folder from my internal hard-drive to it. but after a while I add extra file in my folder in Internal Hard-drive, is there any way or program that let me synch one(or more) folder from internal hard-drive to one (or more) from exteranal-hard-drive.

I don't want use back up program becasue I store Data in my External-Drive in different way of my internal-hard drive, I just want each time I give 2 folder (from different hard) to that program and it copy extra file from one hard to another.

Tanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to take a look at [Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=C26EFA36-98E0-4EE9-A7C5-98D0592D8C52&displaylang=en), If I understand your question, it should be able to do what you need.