# How can I schedule an item to run?

Tags: command-line, windows-registry, scheduled-tasks

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Schedule a job from the Windows command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/8443/schedule-a-job-from-the-windows-command-line)

I'm working on a deployment script for a production machine. I do not have direct access to this machine.

Is there a way to schedule an executable to run each evening from the command line, or through a registry file? The deployer would be logged in as an Administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create scheduled tasks on the command line via `schtasks`. See [here](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/schtasks.mspx) for a full description including examples.